# Jquery ui resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Возможно ли поменять свойства блока в jquery-ui.css. 
Меняю в самом файле jquery-ui.css значения

```
.ui-resizable {
  position:relative;
}
```

на position:static , неменяется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В самом начале не следует менять, ибо правила стилей каскадны - более нижние перебивают более верхние.

Если хочется красивый файл стилей, то надо поэкспериментировать: поменять в самом конце, например. А ещё лучше вычислить, где он проставляется - наверняка не в одном месте.

Если ничего не поможет, то можно добавить важности правилу, прописав так:

```
.ui-resizable {
  position:relative !important;
}
```